# 'bash: make: command not found' on windows after setting environment variable

Tags: windows, bash, makefile, git-bash

I need to install `make` command on windows, and I am told to follow the guide here: https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058#make, which is quoted as follows:

> - Go to ezwinports.
> - Download make-4.1-2-without-guile-w32-bin.zip (get the version without guile).
> - Extract zip.
> - Copy the contents to your Git\mingw64\ merging the folders, but do NOT overwrite/replace any existing files.
>
> (Keep in mind you can easy add make, but it doesn't come packaged with all the standard UNIX build toolchain--so you will have to ensure those are installed and on your PATH, or you will encounter endless error messages.)

But after finishing those steps (extract zip and merging the folders), I run the `make` command and get a `bash: make: command not found` error.

I have added 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin' to my PATH environment variable and have confirmed that file 'make.exe' exists in 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin'.

I find one or two similar problems asked under the comments of the guide website, but they just haven't get answers;

and I also find some answers on stackOverFlow that says using `choco install make` instead, but I'm not sure if these two packages are the same.

Can you give me some suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You don't say how you set PATH, but remember setting it in the system takes effect for FUTURE shells but doesn't change already existing ones.  So, be sure you start a new terminal after changing your PATH, and/or use `echo %PATH%` and make sure the directory appears.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks! I restart my shell and use `echo $PATH` to make sure the directory appears, and now it works.